# CloudFront - CNAME doesn't match in nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx, amazon-cloudfront, cname

I have a distribution with 2 CNAMES: example.com and www.example.com . My goal is redirect www.example.com to example.com

CloudFront points to a LoadBalancer, which points to a EC2 machine. This EC2 machines serves thought a nginx.

My config is:

```
server {
  listen   80;
  server_name default;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/default.access.log;

  root   /xxxx/;
  index  index.html index.htm;

  location /index.html {
        add_header "Cache-Control" "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0";
  }
}

server {
  listen  80;
  server_name ~^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+)$;
  return 301 https://$domain$request_uri;
}
```

The problem is that "server_name" receives "XXX-YYY-ZZZ-WWW.ap-northeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com", not the CNAME (so I don't have the information for get the domain).

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try to enable forwarding of Host header in CloudFront (see details here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html). Then you should use Host header value in your nginx config to trigger redirect